# Jetpack Compose: how to right align container that wraps content

Tags: android, kotlin, view, alignment, jetpack-compose

I'd like to right-align a text bubble like so:

[image]

What do I need to do to get the desired result, and what exactly is going on as far as when each view in the sequence is being measured?

Answer (score 1):

The `Row` composable has a modifier property set to `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` which makes it fill the width of its parent container. The `horizontalArrangement` property of the Row is set to `Arrangement.End` which aligns the child elements of the Row to the right end of the container.

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End) {
    Text(
         text = "Yes", modifier = Modifier
           .background(Color.LightGray, RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
           .padding(10.dp)
     )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spacer with weight to achieve this.

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()){
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    Text(modifier = Modifier
        .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.light_gray), shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
        .padding(8.dp),text = "Yes")
}
```

First create a Row with max width. Now create a Spacer with weight 1f which occupy all the available space in your row. Now whatever you add after the spacer will be aligned at the end of your row.